# Determine the radius of convergence of the following power series.?..

Tags: power-series

Determine the radius of convergence of the following  power series.

a) $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{ x^{6n+2}}{(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n^2}}$

my attempts:  by applying the ratio test i got $ \frac {a_n}{a_{n+1}}$ =$\frac{ x^{6n+2}}{(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n^2}}$.$\frac{(1+\frac{1}{n+1})^{(n+1)^2}}{ x^{6n+8}}$

i got $ \frac {a_n}{a_{n+1}}$ = $\frac{e}{x^6}$

now  i don't know  ...how  to find the  radius  of convergence of given power series.....Pliz help me

thanks  in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $\frac {a_n}{a_{n+1}} \to \frac{e}{x^6}$ we get

$\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} \to \frac{x^6}{e}$ .

The ratio test shows that the power series converges for $|x|<e^{1/6}$ and diverges for  $|x|>e^{1/6}$, hence the radius of convergence is $e^{1/6}$.

Comment: thanks  a  lots @Fred

Answer (score 0):

First of all, typically we apply the Ratio Test as $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|$, but you have it upside down. Also, don't forget about the limit! Your statement that
$$\color{red}{\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}=\frac{e}{x^6}}$$
is false; the correct statement is that
$$\color{blue}{\lim_{n\to\infty}}{\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}=\frac{e}{x^6}}.$$
Other than that, you did a fine job! You just need to flip it over, restore the correct notation — absolute values and limits, and remember that we want the output of the Ratio Test to be less than $1$ to ensure convergence of a series:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\frac{x^6}{e} \implies \text{the series converges when } \frac{x^6}{e}<1.$$
Solving this inequality — and don't forget the absolute value $|x|$ when you take the sixth root! — you'll find the radius of convergence.

Comment: Thanks  a lots @zipirovich